# how to add new groups to the special characters drop down in ckeditor5?

Tags: wysiwyg

As the title says I am looking to add an new group of characters for use in the special characters drop down displayed below in ckeditor5 along side the likes of Latin and currency.

In my specific case I need the Greek alphabet.

[The dropdown in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsrcT.png)

How is this done?